# What does mean ConfigurationProperty.IsDefaultCollection since it is not explained?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration-files

I read Microsoft helps but it is very poor and I have not idea what it does. I think that it can be skipped and it is redundant because if child element is collection there is not reason to specify that it is collection.

What is use of this [ConfigurationProperty.IsDefaultCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationproperty.isdefaultcollection?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: "This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code." So why do you want to know?  It looks like an X/Y problem.

Comment: Problem is that they write such rubbish everywhere "This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code." even it should be used. See they write same rubbish but is should be used "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationproperty.isrequired?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Configuration_ConfigurationProperty_IsRequired"

Comment: Yes, it is on all members of  ConfigurationProperty. So why do you think you need that class?   The implication here is that it might change or disappear in a future version. And ranting won't help.

Comment: Documentation won't help much here, but you can check the reference code to see how this property is being used, https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration,namespaces